# Instances exponentially increasing - eating memory

Tags: java, swing, memory-leaks, jbutton, jtogglebutton

I've created a Minesweeper game that generates a 2-D array of JButtons every time a new game is started. The problem is that memory usage increases exponentially(JProfiler says it's the JButtons). It seems that not only are the old Jbutton instances being kept in memory, but the number of instances double. How can I tell it to get rid of the old JButtons? Thanks

```
private JButton[][] but;
but = new JButton[row][col];
for (int i = 0;i<row;i++)
{    
  for (int j = 0;j<col;j++){
      but[i][j]= new JButton();
      but[i][j].setName(i+":"+j);
      mine.add(but[i][j]);
      but[i][j].addMouseListener(this);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why don't the old instances go away?

Comment: Do you ever delete the buttons from the component when adding the new ones? Apart from that, it does not look like a lot like a memory leak. PS: Tyler answer of reusing instead of recreating is a good one.

Comment: Also, do you mean exponentially literally or it is just a way of meaning "very quickly"?

Comment: Probably the mine.add(but[i][j]); is maintaining the reference to the old instances.

Comment: Exponentially, they double each time 100-200-400-800...etc

Comment: Before this code executes I have a mine =new JPanel();

Comment: Try explicitly destroying the old one? Are you just hiding it?

Comment: I think this is "geometrically". Anyway, usually it should grow aritmetically (100-200-300). Are you sure your code is not inside a loop? I would advise logging an statement each time you create a new Button to check why it rises so sharply.

Comment: How would one explicity destroy the old one?

Comment: If you are creating a new mine panel each time, then maybe something is holding the reference to the old one. Anyway you need to check with the profile who is holding the references, by examining the denominator tree. Probably JProfiler has this feature too, if not I suggest you to try the Eclipse MAT.

Comment: I tried mine.removeAll() which didnt help :(

Comment: ....figured it out, seems as if I was creating a new "New Button" button each time and the function would be called several times each time

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like a classic use case for the pool pattern.

Allocate ONE grid's worth of buttons on program start, and reuse them for each game.

Comment: But each new game might have a different size grid

Comment: Ok, so use a 1d grid, size i*j when i and j represent the maximal number of buttons you might need. Get a given cells address with `(row  * numrows)+col`. This way the existing structure will work with any number of cells up to whatever max you allocate.